# Download all contents of a directory automatically?

Tags: download, http, download-manager, file-download

[Here](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/) you can see a directory that contains some sub-directory and there a a lot of PDF files. Is there any way to download all of them automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [GetThemAll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/getthemall-downloader/nbkekaeindpfpcoldfckljplboolgkfm?hl=en) chrome extension. Or you can check [this](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-download-all-files-from-a-folder-on-a-website-or-ftp/) link for info on `Wget` and other options.

Comment: Nice extension, Thanks. But it doesn't explore directories to find files.

Comment: @Am1r Have you come across [this](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-download-all-files-from-a-folder-on-a-website-or-ftp/) link?

Comment: You could maybe try saving the website too.

Comment: That link was great. Thanks. I tried a tool named `Wget` introduced there, and it is doing it for me successful. May I ask you to add this tool to your answer to check your answer.

Comment: @Am1r Glad it worked for you mate! I added the link to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use "httrack" software. It copies the website. Hopefully it will diwnload pdf also. There is a mobile app also for httrack.